Spark SQL : order of placing the select column changes the resultant dataframe when count is used
I have a dataframe, where I want to get the count of distinct calltypes (column name).
When I tried using this spark dataframe transformation code, I get the data as expected:
fire_df_convrtd_grpby = fire_df_convrtd \
                              .select("CallType") \
                              .where("CallType is not null") \
                              .groupBy("CallType") \
                              .count() \
                              .orderBy("count", ascending=False) \
                              .show()


But when I change the order of the select column, if I have the where method in the beginning and select after the count method then the resulting dataset is different:
fire_df_convrtd_grpby = fire_df_convrtd \
                            .where("CallType is not null") \
                            .groupBy("CallType") \
                            .count() \
                            .select("CallType") \
                            .orderBy("count", ascending=False) \
                            .show()


Why this change of behaviour? As the select column comes in the last does it override the data from count?

So what you are doing in the second example is that you're selecting only the "CallType" column out of all the columns in your DataFrame. A possible solution is to also include the "Count" in your select list as bellow
fire_df_convrtd_grpby = (
    df.where("CallType is not null")
    .groupBy("CallType")
    .count()
    .select("CallType", "count")
    .orderBy("count", ascending=False)
    .show()
)

